# Proof of a Burnside theorem without character theory?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Burnside proved, by use of character theory, that if a finite group $G$ has a conjugacy class $C$ such that $\vert C \vert$ is a prime power $> 1$, then $G$ is not simple. Let us call this statement "Burnside's non-simplicity theorem".

From this theorem, Burnside deduced easily his "$p^{a}q^{b}$ theorem" : every finite group whose order has at most two distinct prime factors is solvable.

It is well known that Burnside's $p^{a}q^{b}$ theorem can be proved indepedently from character theory. Can "Burnside's non-simplicity theorem" also be proved indepedently from character theory ?

Comment: If would help if you'd show a sketch proof using character theory

Comment: Sorry, for a moment I thought your question was "Can Burnside's non-simplicity Theorem also be proved independently from Group Theory"...

Comment: @reuns : I think that any person who knows the first elements of character theory knows the proof of "Burnside's non-simplicity theorem" that uses character theory. I never saw an introduction to character theory that doesn't give this proof.

Comment: As you pointed out, Burnside's $p^aq^b$ can easily be deduced from what you call "Burnside's non-simplicity theorem", and this without using any character theory. So you essentially ask for a purely group-theoretic proof of Burnside's $p^aq^b$-theorem. If the known such proofs by Bender rsp. Goldschmidt and Matsuyama cannot be used for proving "Burnside's non-simplicity theorem", then it is unlikely that someone will be able to answer your question.

Comment: MSE is useful to share our knowledge and to make it precise and clean. If you understand a proof and you ask about modifying it, then you are supposed to start by explaining it and show what exactly you'd like to change. Otherwise your question is useless to you and to anybody else.

Comment: @reuns : I only wish to know if the literature contains a proof of "Burnside's non-simplicity theorem" without character theory. I don't expect that a member of MSE will invent such a proof.

Comment: @Eugene Zhang . Sorry, but I was not interested by a prood of Burnside's solvability theorem without character theory, I was interested by a proof of Burnside's non-simplicity theorem without character theory.